# could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, spinner

I an activity that uses ArrayAdapter to display checkboxes and spinners on screen, depending on definitions in xml. 
the user checks the desired checkboxes and chooses from the desired spinners and clicks "save".
my problem occures when a spinner is not visible on screen (due to scrolling), then the crash happens.

my code :

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {
    InputStream DetailsFile;
    Map<String, List<String>> details;
    ListView list;
    String[] titlesArray;
    ArrayList<String> types;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> spinnerPositions = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        try {
            DetailsFile = am.open("Details.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        types = new ArrayList<String>();
        details = ParseDetailsXML(DetailsFile);

        Set<String> keys = details.keySet();
        titlesArray = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        DetailsAdapter adapter = new DetailsAdapter(this, titlesArray, details,
                types);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> ParseDetailsXML(InputStream is) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(is, "UTF-8");
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();
            List<String> detailList = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                Node child = children.item(i);
                if (child instanceof Element) {
                    Element childElement = (Element) child;
                    this.types.add(childElement.getAttribute("type"));
                    NodeList details = childElement.getChildNodes();
                    String detail = childElement.getNodeName();
                    detailList = new LinkedList<String>();
                    if (childElement.getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("dropdown")) {
                        detailList.add("No Selection");
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < details.getLength(); j++) {

                        Node detailND = details.item(j);
                        if (detailND instanceof Element) {
                            Element detailElement = (Element) detailND;
                            String text = detailElement.getAttribute("val");
                            detailList.add(text);

                        }

                    }
                    map.put(detail, detailList);

                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ;
        return map;

    }

    public class DetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        String[] titleArray;
        Map<String, List<String>> details;
        List<String> types;

        DetailsAdapter(Context c, String[] titles,
                Map<String, List<String>> details, List<String> types) {
            super(c, R.layout.details_single_row, R.id.text_view, titles);
            this.context = c;
            this.titleArray = titles;
            this.details = details;
            this.types = types;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            String mCurrentType = types.get(position);
            if (mCurrentType.contains("checkbox")) {
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_single_row,
                        parent, false);
                TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
                ViewGroup checkBoxContainer = (ViewGroup) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContainer);

                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);

                List<String> checkBoxTitles = details.get(titleArray[position]);
                int i = 1;
                for (String value : checkBoxTitles) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(context);
                    checkbox.setId(i);
                    checkbox.setText(value);
                    checkbox.setTextSize(35);
                    checkBoxContainer.addView(checkbox);
                    i++;
                }
                return row;

            } else {
                View row = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.details_single_row_dropdown, parent, false);
                TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                List<String> spinnerTitles = details.get(titleArray[position]);

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.spinner_details);
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        spinnerTitles);

                spinnerArrayAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                spinner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                return row;

            }

        }

    }


    public void SaveButton(View v) {
        myGlobals.Details = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        myGlobals.Accessories = null;
        spinnerPositions = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        View row;
        CheckBox checkbox = null;
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(details.keySet());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
            String title = titles.get(i); // title
            List<String> valueList = details.get(title); // the list ascosiated
                                                            // with that title
            row = list.getChildAt(i);
            String type = types.get(i);
            if (type.contains("checkbox")) {
                ArrayList<String> checkedTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
                ViewGroup checkBoxContainer = (ViewGroup) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContainer);
                for (int j = 0; j < checkBoxContainer.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    checkbox = (CheckBox) checkBoxContainer.findViewById(j + 1);
                    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        String checkBoxTitle = checkbox.getText().toString();
                        checkedTitles.add(checkBoxTitle);

                    }
                }
                if (!checkedTitles.isEmpty()) {
                    myGlobals.Details.put(title, checkedTitles);
                }
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> selectedItem = new ArrayList<String>();
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.spinner_details);
                spinnerPositions.put(i, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                selectedItem.add(selected);
                myGlobals.Details.put(title, selectedItem);
            }
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Accesories Saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : myGlobals.Details
                .entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> list2 = entry.getValue();
            String joined = TextUtils.join(",", list2);
            sb.append(key + " : " + joined + " . ");
            myGlobals.Accessories = sb.toString();

        }
        Log.d("YANIV", myGlobals.Accessories);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putStringArrayList("types", types);
        outState.putStringArray("titlesArray", titlesArray);
        outState.putSerializable("spinnerPositions", spinnerPositions);
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : myGlobals.Details
                .entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> list = entry.getValue();
            outState.putStringArrayList(key, list);
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] titles = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("titlesArray");
        ArrayList<String> typesArrayList = savedInstanceState
                .getStringArrayList("types");
        spinnerPositions = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("spinnerPositions");
        for (String value : typesArrayList) {
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            View row;
            CheckBox checkbox = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                String currentTitle = titles[i];
                ArrayList<String> currentList = savedInstanceState
                        .getStringArrayList(currentTitle);
                row = list.getChildAt(i);
                if (value.contains("checkbox")) {
                    ViewGroup checkBoxContainer = (ViewGroup) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContainer);
                    for (int j = 0; j < checkBoxContainer.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        checkbox = (CheckBox) checkBoxContainer
                                .findViewById(j + 1);
                        if (currentList.contains(checkbox.getText())) {
                            checkbox.setChecked(true);

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.spinner_details);
                    spinner.setSelection(spinnerPositions.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

my logcat crash :

```
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109): Process: com.tfl.techmanager, PID: 10109
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    ... 11 more
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    at com.tfl.techmanager.DetailsActivity.SaveButton(DetailsActivity.java:226)
06-14 17:15:03.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10109):    ... 14 more
```

it crashed in line :

```
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinner_details);
```

and the crash occurs when the spinner is not visible on screen due to scrolling (but it IS available)

Comment: can you post your layout ?

Comment: @S.Thiongane unfortunately no..